Create a separate subscription, for each subscription product purchased in the transaction
I want to sell a virtual product, where each bought product should be it's own subscription, to be able to cancel just one of the bought products, without cancelling all products bought in this order.
For example, if a customer purchases 2 x monthly subscription products and 3 x yearly subscription products in the one transaction, 5 x subscriptions should be created with each including a single line item for that product. Even though it's the same product.
I have been trying to solve this by using this code:
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'create_individual_subscriptions', 10, 2);

function create_individual_subscriptions($order, $data) {
    // Check if WooCommerce Subscriptions plugin is active
    if (!class_exists('WC_Subscriptions_Product')) return;

    $cart = WC()->cart;

    foreach ($cart->get_cart() as $cart_item) {
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];

        // Check if the product is a subscription
        if (WC_Subscriptions_Product::is_subscription($product_id)) {
            // Add the subscription product to the order
            $order->add_product(get_product($product_id), $cart_item['quantity']);

            // Get the product's subscription details
            $billing_period = WC_Subscriptions_Product::get_period($product_id);
            $billing_interval = WC_Subscriptions_Product::get_interval($product_id);

            // Create a new subscription for each product in the cart
            $subscription = wcs_create_subscription(array(
                'order_id' => $order->get_id(),
                'status' => 'pending', // You can set the initial status as needed
                'billing_period' => $billing_period,
                'billing_interval' => $billing_interval,
                // Add more subscription details as needed
            ));

            // Add the subscription to the order
            $order->add_item($subscription);
        }
    }

    // Calculate totals for the order
    $order->calculate_totals();

    // Remove the cart items after adding subscriptions to the order
    $cart->empty_cart();
}

But it "only" creates, one subscription with each product in the same subscription...
